# res.render's callback will execut twice in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

guys.I have a question need help.

code like follow:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  console.log('do...')
  res.render('index.jade')

});
```

console print:

```
do...
do...
```

it print twice.

but when I use below code instead of above. something has changed!

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  console.log('do...')
  res.send('hello world!')

});
```

the callback will execut once.

How to explain this phenomenon?

Comment: On locally testing this behaviour, I noticed that there are 2 calls made only when opening the page in Chrome (v 53.0.2785.143) when opened in a new browser tab.

There was only a single call made when using `curl`, or opening the page in Firefox. Perhaps someone could provide an explanation to why!

Comment: I don't see the two log messages, in Chrome, Firefox, or with cUrl - have setup  a basic test case here: https://github.com/itsravenous/stack-40394194

Do you still see it hitting the route twice with that project?